# Cypher query whether a node is connected to multiple nodes in a filtered group

Tags: neo4j, cypher, filtering, processing-efficiency, cypher-3.1

I am experimenting with a graph representing `(:Shopper)`'s who `-[:Make]->(:Purchase)`'s and each purchase `-[:Contains]->(:Item)`'s. The challenge is that I want to compare the quantity of Item A each Shopper bought on their most recent purchase. Eliminating Items with only one :Contains relationship won't work, because the Item may have been bought in an earlier purchase as well.

I can get data on the set of all Items in all Shoppers' most recent Purchases with

```
MATCH (s:Shopper)-->(p:Purchase)
WITH s, max(p.Time) AS latest
MATCH (s)-->(p:Purchase)
WHERE p.Time = latest
MATCH (p)-[c:Contains]->(i:Item)
RETURN s.Name, p.Time, c.Quantity, i.Name
```

but now I want to replace the second MATCH clause with something like

```
MATCH (p:Purchase)-[c1:Contains]->(i:Item)<-[c2:Contains]-(p:Purchase)
```

and it doesn't return any results. I suspect that this looks for items that have two :Contains relationships to the SAME Purchase. I want to get the :Contains relationships on two DIFFERENT Purchases in the same filtered group. How can I do this efficiently? I really want to avoid having to redo the filtering process on the second Purchase node.

Comment: Hello! Can you create a [Console](http://console.neo4j.org) with a sample data set and tell us the expected result? Thanks!

Comment: sure, its at http://console.neo4j.org/r/a5eqfx. the current query gives all items in most recent purchase, my desired query would only return the rows with banana, since that is the only item in more than one of the target purchases

Comment: The data model of that console does not match what is presented in the question. A label and a type were changed.

Comment: sorry, it demonstrates the same concept though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

In your top query, you do not need to `MATCH` twice to get the latest `Purchase` for each `Shopper` (see below).

In your `MATCH` snippet, you are using the same `p` variable for both `Purchase` nodes, so of course they are forced to be the same node.

Here is a query that should return a set of data for each `Item` that was in the latest `Purchase`s of multiple `Shopper`s:

```
MATCH (s:Shopper)-[:Make]->(pur:Purchase)
WITH s, pur
ORDER BY pur.Time DESC
WITH s, HEAD(COLLECT(pur)) AS p
MATCH (p)-[c:Contains]->(i:Item)
WITH i, COLLECT({shopper: s.Name, time: p.Time, quantity: c.Quantity}) AS set
WHERE SIZE(set) > 1
RETURN i.Name AS item, set;
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=f4qdq4) that demonstrates the query with your sample data (with corrections to label and type names). It produces this result:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| item     | set                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "Banana" | [{shopper=Mandy, time=213, quantity=12},{shopper=Joe, time=431, quantity=5},{shopper=Steve, time=320, quantity=1}] |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, but I only want to get Items that have a Contains relationship with multiple nodes in the set of nodes that p represents

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you only want `Item`s that were in the latest `Purchase`s of multiple `Shopper`s?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly it

Comment: That answers my question :).